# Apache Access log recieved request time issue

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, logging, ubuntu-14.04, apache2

Please see the strange situation with received request time in the Apache(2.4.7) access log in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
IP1 - - [14/Dec/2016:00:00:02 +0300] "GET /portal/get.php?filename=file1.mpg HTTP/1.1" 206 194292 "-" "Lavf53.32.100"
IP1 - - [14/Dec/2016:00:00:02 +0300] "GET /portal/get.php?filename=file1.mpg HTTP/1.1" 206 140716 "-" "Lavf53.32.100"
IP1 - - [14/Dec/2016:00:00:02 +0300] "GET /portal/get.php?filename=file1.mpg HTTP/1.1" 206 191396 "-" "Lavf53.32.100"
IP2 - - [13/Dec/2016:23:59:59 +0300] "GET /portal/get.php?filename=file2.mpg HTTP/1.1" 206 6010910 "-" "Lavf53.32.100"
IP2 - - [14/Dec/2016:00:00:03 +0300] "GET /portal/get.php?filename=file2.mpg HTTP/1.1" 206 189950 "-" "Lavf53.32.100"
IP2 - - [14/Dec/2016:00:00:03 +0300] "GET /portal/get.php?filename=file2.mpg HTTP/1.1" 206 191398 "-" "Lavf53.32.100"
IP2 - - [14/Dec/2016:00:00:03 +0300] "GET /portal/get.php?filename=file2.mpg HTTP/1.1" 206 237734 "-" "Lavf53.32.100"
IP2 - - [14/Dec/2016:00:00:03 +0300] "GET /portal/get.php?filename=file2.mpg HTTP/1.1" 206 194294 "-" "Lavf53.32.100"
IP3 - - [13/Dec/2016:23:59:34 +0300] "GET /portal/get.php?filename=file3.mpg HTTP/1.1" 206 5374262 "-" "Lavf53.32.100"
IP1 - - [14/Dec/2016:00:00:02 +0300] "GET /portal/get.php?filename=file1.mpg HTTP/1.1" 206 5465012 "-" "Lavf53.32.100"
IP1 - - [14/Dec/2016:00:00:06 +0300] "GET /portal/get.php?filename=file1.mpg HTTP/1.1" 206 184156 "-" "Lavf53.32.100"
IP1 - - [14/Dec/2016:00:00:06 +0300] "GET /portal/get.php?filename=file1.mpg HTTP/1.1" 206 121892 "-" "Lavf53.32.100"
```

Any ideas why the time  isn't arranged ascending? 
Is this an Apache issue or something wrong with my server or no need to worry about this?  
 What else I need to check on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time recorded in the log is the time the request was initially received. However, the log entry is not actually written until the request is completed. Thus, requests can appear out of sequence, when some requests take more time to complete.